# How to run php file

Tags: php

I have added this to path:C:\xampp\php. separate by semi colon, & when I put this address (localhost/myfiles/hello.php) on the browser the file was opened properly, so, why cant it be opened in cmd?& I always get this message:Windows cant open this file.

Comment: You need to go into the php directory using `cd` through cmd to get to it and use DjDarkViper's answer.

Comment: Not necessarily, because he did mention he added the path to the PHP executable to his `PATH` global environment variable. This allows him to run any executable in that directory, from anywhere on the system (in this case, php.exe, which Windows CMD automatically adds the `.exe` aspect, allowing you to just say `php`)

Comment: @DJDarkViper good point, didn't see that there

Comment: The same reason why `c:\progra~1` doesn't work, but `cd c:\progra~1` works

Answer (score 4):

command is looking for an absolute path to the file, not an address

`$ php ../path/to/myfiles/hello.php`

**edit**

Upon re-reating your question, I could also assume your forgetting to add the `php` command to the command. Adding the path to PHP in XAMPP allows you to execute the php executable through the command line interface.  So you run `php` and then the switch configs and then the filepath.

Comment: OK, I put this command you gave & get this:couldnt open this file.

Comment: if you type `php -v` what do you see?

Comment: PHP 5.5.11 (cli) (built: Apr 8 2014 15:07:14)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

Comment: Now I sucseeded opening files by writing this syntax:php C:\xampp\htdocs\myfiles\jim.php  my syntax was wrong, Thank you

Comment: And yes I was forgetting to add php command to the command. Thank you

Comment: Glad everything got resolved :) Mind check-marking my answer for me? :)